# why there is an unexpected space when jumping to another page in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, navigationview

I want to jump to another page using NavigationLink, but there is an unexpected space at the top of the screen as the picture shows below. This didn't happen before. I don't know whether it's because my front page or the page I try to jump to.

**the start page**

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomePage: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
                
                NavigationLink(destination: chartDiretor()) {
                       Text("clike")
                    
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: chartDiretor()) {
                       Text("clike")
                    
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**the destination page**

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{
                Text("something")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
}
```

[when clike the navigationLink. space highlighted with red rectangle line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvQE3.jpg)

[what the the page I try to jump to looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F7mn.jpg)

Comment: Remove NavigationView from HomePage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is, you've stacked 2 `NavigationView`s on top of one another. One in `SwiftUIView` which is again embedded in another `NavigationView` in `HomePage`. Your current View hierarchy looks like,

```
NavigationView // First NavigationView
|- SwiftUIView
   |- NavigationView // Second NavigationView
      |- Some Content
```

When it should actually look like,

```
NavigationView // First and ONLY NavigationView
|- SwiftUIView
   |- Some Content
```

---

So, to fix this you can remove the `NavigationView` in `SwiftUIView` like the following,

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List{
            Text("something")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Country") // Set the Navigation title here
    }
}
```